# How to integrate CanCan with multiple devise models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancan

How would I go about defining abilities for several devise models?

Answer (score 18):

Let's assume your app has two separate Devise-powered user models called `User` and `Admin`. This means you use methods like `current_user` and `current_admin` side by side.

Let's further assume that you only have/want a single `Ability` class, which contains all your CanCan permission settings...

```ruby
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new
    case user
    when User
      can :create, Comment
      can :read, :all
    when Admin
      can :manage, :all
    end
  end
end
```

This is exactly what others have proposed, but there's another step you have to take.

By default, CanCan assumes that the method `current_user` exists and will return a User object to compare with your `Ability` settings. However, our admin users can be found using `current_admin`. Without telling CanCan where to find admin objects, they never get reviewed, and thus never get permissions; **we must change the defaults when dealing with an admin.**

Add the following to `application_controller.rb`...

```ruby
def current_ability
  if admin_signed_in?
    @current_ability ||= Ability.new(current_admin)
  else
    @current_ability ||= Ability.new(current_user)
  end
end
```

Now our Ability class will look at the Admin object if one is available, and fall back on a normal User when none is present.

Further development allows us to move Admin permissions into their own separate Ability class...

```
def current_ability
  if admin_signed_in?
    @current_ability ||= AdminPowers.new(current_admin)
  else
    @current_ability ||= Ability.new(current_user)
  end
end
```

For more info, see [Changing Defaults](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Changing-Defaults) in the Wiki. Kudos to [Stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/477037/stefan) for pointing me at the proper article.

FYI -- **CanCan is dead, long live [CanCanCan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan)!** Up to date with bug fixes and new features. Same namespaces, so it's just a drop-in gem replacement in your Gemfile.

```
gem 'cancancan', '~> 1.8'
```

Comment: after searching i finally found the complete answer

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me -

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    if user.is_a?(Admin)
      can :manage, :all
    elsif user.is_a?(User)
      can :create, Comment
      can :read, :all
    else
      can :read, :all
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The current user model is passed to the `Ability#initialize`, so you can just check its class:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(model)
    case model
    when Admin
      can :manage, :all
    when User
      can :create, Comment
      can :read, :all
    else
      can :read, :all
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you Stefan. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be working. It applies only the User case and else but not the Admin. Whenever I login as an admin I only have guest privileges. Probably I'm doing something wrong but I can't figure out.

Comment: Maybe `Ability#initialize` is not being called for your Admin. Add some logging and check out [Changing Defaults](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Changing-Defaults).