# Rails, Devise multiple models login and their sessions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, devise, cancan

I have two models that are generated by **devise**: `Partner` and `Admin`. Each of them has their own `sessions currents and etc`. Some controllers require only `Admin` that logged in, some controllers require either `Partner` or `Admin` to be logged in.

There is `:authenticate_admin!` and `:authenticate_partner!` methods that will be called in my controllers `before_action`.

I also use **CanCanCan** to define both of them roles.

That gives multiple questions:

1. If I logged in as `Partner` then I opened page where `Admin` must be logged in and I logged in, that means that I will have two `sessions` at once?
2. I logged in as `Partner` when I am also `Admin`, that mens I need to destroy session of `Admin`. How to make Devise to destroy other model sessions when current model is logged in?
3. Do I need to add something like this in controller where or `Admin` or `Partner` is needed?

   ```
   before_action :authenticate_partner!
   before_action :authenticate_admin!
   ```
4. And the last question is: how I can make `Partners` open pages (that means access controllers) only that is allowed by **CanCanCan** ?

I wanted to use `authorize_resource`, it asks only one model per controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes. There are two independent devise scopes for each model, using different session variables.
2. Devise does not destroy a scope session when you sign in the other scope, but you can do it manually. There is devise method `sign_out(scope)`. In your case, you can call `sign_out(:partner)` and `sign_out(:admin)` when you need it. There also must be methods like this `sign_out_partner`, `sign_out_admin`, automatically provided for your scopes by Devise. Also, pay attention to `config.sign_out_all_scopes` devise option.
3. Yes, those filters restrict access to the controller's actions.
4. I hope this will help [How to integrate CanCan with multiple devise models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11088795/how-to-integrate-cancan-with-multiple-devise-models)

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need two models ? Maybe you can just have one model (call it `User`) with a role as an integer ?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   enum role: [ :partner, :admin ]
end
```

Comment: Theese models are so different. It will be better keep them as spearate models